# Node: Split CSV by value

Tags: node.js, csv

I am trying to split a CSV into new CSV files based on the value of an attribute field. After testing a few different modules it looks like fast-csv is a good choice. However, I need some help on how split the files by the attribute.

I initially thought about doing a transform:

```
.transform(function(data){
    if (data.AttributeValue == '10') {
        return {
            data
        };
    } else if (data.AttributeValue == '5') {
        return {
            data
        };
    } else {
        data
    })
```

})

Or I could use the validate:

```
.validate(function(data){
   return data.AttributeValue == '10';
})
```

What I need help with is which one to use and how to send the row of data to different writeStreams.

```
.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("10.csv", {encoding: "utf8"}));
.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("5.csv", {encoding: "utf8"}));
.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("Other.csv", {encoding: "utf8"}));
```

I have done this in Python but trying to migrate this to Node is proving trickier than I thought.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this, to send the data from your validation test to another function.

```
.validate(function(data){
    if(data.attribute = '10'){
        ten(data);
    } else {
        notTen(data);
    }
});
```

Then you can simply use a CSV writer to write out to CSV, for each CSV you'll need to open a csv writer:

```
var csvStream = csv.createWriteStream({headers: true}),
    writableStream = fs.createWriteStream("not10.csv");

writableStream.on("finish", function(){
  console.log("DONE!");
});

csvStream.pipe(writableStream);

function writeToCsv(data){
    csvStream.write(data);
}
```

Repeat for each CSV you need to write to.

Might not be the best way to do it, but I am fairly new to this, and it seems to work.